# ParseQuery images and storing result in ArrayList and display using recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arrays, parsing, android-bitmap

Using Android Studio and Java and Parse as backend server.

I am able to capture and upload images to Parse fine.

Now I need to download all uploaded images and store them in an ArrayList.

Then I want to display the ArrayList result using RecyclerView.

I am displaying everything in a Fragment and activities.

I have .. MainFragment.java, MainFragment.xml, DisplayAdapter.java

The MainFragment.xml has the RecyclerView.

I am able to view one image if add it to ImageView variable using imageAdded.setImageBitmap(bitmap).

Any idea how I can add the retrieved images to the arraylist as it keeps giving me errors whatever I do.

```
private RecyclerView recyclerViewPosts;
private PostAdapter postAdapter;
private List<Post> postList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    recyclerViewPosts = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_posts);
    recyclerViewPosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerViewPosts.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), postList);
    recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(postAdapter);


    readPosts();

    return view;
}




private void readPosts() {

    // Query the Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query  = new ParseQuery("ImageUpload");


    //Sort query by Ascending order as per created date
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if(objects.size() >0 && e == null){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"I am trying to show image" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                for(ParseObject object: objects){
                    ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("ImageFile");
                    file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if(e == null && data != null){
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                                
                                //postList.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                //images.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                postList.add(bitmap);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Showing Image Failed ......" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //objectRetrievalFailed();
            }
        }
    });

    postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the display adapter XML file

```
private Context mContext;
private List<Post> mPosts;

private ParseUser currentUser;



public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPosts) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPosts = mPosts;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
    return new PostAdapter.Viewholder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position) {

    currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    Post post = mPosts.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(post.getImageType()).into(holder.postImage);
    holder.description.setText(post.getImageDescription());

    Picasso.get().load(post.getImageTypeSub()).into(holder.imageProfile);
    holder.username.setText(currentUser.getUsername());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPosts.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imageProfile;
    public ImageView postImage;
    
    public TextView username;
   
    SocialTextView description;


    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Using this constructor we Link above variables to elements in Post_Item layout.
        imageProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);

        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);

        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: " it keeps giving me errors ", such as?

Comment: The error is in postList.add(bitmap);
it underlines bitmap and suggest the I change the field postList type to List<Bitmap> which I tried but gave me other errors.

Comment: If that list is only ued for storing bitmaps. have you tried using `ArrayList<Bitmap> postList= new ArrayList<Bitmap>()` instead of `List` ?

Comment: No. It is to store the image and its related info like username, type, description, etc.
Any ideas how to do it. The code is working for Firebase but I am not sure to make it work for Parse. I am able to view the count of posts retrieved.